# I have a sticky header and within header i have jquery auto suggestion when we scroll the page then auto suggestion is also scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a sticky header within header i have auto suggestion when i scroll the page then autosuggestion is also scrolling. 
I want[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbxHx.jpg) auto suggestion also stick with header

Comment: Could you post jsfiddle or sandbox without it its hard to find what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try this css on auto suggestion parent div

```css
.ClassName {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Actully jquery auto suggestion bind on bottom of the page so how can i make parent div?